Who was Riemann's most admired mathematician?
And is there any historical information for that? For example, a letter from Riemann saying that he admires someone the most?

Erwin Neuenschwander, "Lettres de Bernhard Riemann à sa famille." Cahiers du séminaire d'histoire des mathématiques, Serie 1, Vol. 2 (1981), pp. 85-131 (online) cites the following from a letter by Bernhard Riemann to his brother Wilhelm, written at Göttingen on September 28, 1852:

am Dienstag Nachmittag schon sagte mir Gauß, als ich bei ihm Visite machte, daß
der Prof. Dirichlet aus Berlin hier wäre. Ich habe gerade bei ihm in Berlin viel gehört und halte ihn nächst Gauß für den größten jetzt lebenden Mathematiker; auch Gauß hält große Stücke auf ihn.

My translation: "When I paid a visit to Gauss on Tuesday he told me that professor Dirichlet from Berlin is in town. I heard many of his lectures, especially in Berlin, and consider him, next to Gauss, the greatest currently living mathematician; Gauss, too, holds him in high esteem."
From the biographical sketch by R. Dedekind, "Bernhard Riemann's Lebenslauf." In R.  Dedekind and H. Weber (eds.), Bernhard Riemann's gesammelte mathematische Werke und wissenschaftlicher Nachlass. Leipzig: Teubner 1876, pp. 507-526, one sees (p. 512) that Riemann attended the University of Berlin from Easter 1847 through Easter 1849, and that he attended lectures by Dirichlet on number theory, definite integrals, and partial differential equations.

"große" not "groBe" Stücke --- that's a punny typo. (Tried to edit it myself, software won't let me because it's only one character.)
